Nginx not blocking access to .php
I'm trying to make nginx block access to all .php files. As I understand, the code below should work (after sudo systemctl restart nginx). Instead, nginx is forwarding to my server where I can see at Event Viewer the error.
location ~ \.php$ {
        return 403;
}

Nginx access log:
x.x.x.x - - [19/Jul/2024:08:09:17 -0300] "GET /test-user.php HTTP/1.1" 500 1405 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

UPDATE - full config
http {
        keepalive_timeout               60s;
        proxy_read_timeout              60s;
        proxy_send_timeout              60s;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5s;

        client_max_body_size    2M;

        sendfile                        on;
        tcp_nopush                      on;
        types_hash_max_size             2048;
        server_tokens                   off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;

        include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type    application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
        ssl_ciphers                     ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256>
        ssl_session_timeout             1d;
        ssl_session_cache               shared:MozSSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets             off;

        gzip on;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        include         /etc/nginx/block_bad_robots.conf;

        server  {
                listen          443 ssl;
                server_name     sw.contoso.com;

                error_log       /var/log/nginx/sw.contoso.com.error.log;
                access_log      /var/log/nginx/sw.contoso.com.access.log;

                ssl_certificate         /etc/certs/manual-fullchain.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key     /etc/certs/manual-privkey.pem;

                ssl_dhparam             /etc/certs/dhparams.pem;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        return 403;
                }

                location ~* \.cgi {
                        return 403;
                }

                location ~* (\.env|\.aws) {
                        return 403;
                }

                location ~* ^/wp {
                        return 403;
                }

                location ^~ / {

                        if ($bad_robots) {
                                return 403;
                        }

                        proxy_pass              https://192.168.10.1:443;
                        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                }

                location /Settings {

                        if ($bad_robots) {
                                return 403;
                        }

                        client_max_body_size    100M;
                        proxy_pass              https://192.168.10.1:443;
                        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                }

                error_page      400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 =200        /error/unauthorized.html;
                location = /error/unauthorized.html {
                        internal;
                        alias           /etc/nginx/html/error/;
                        try_files       /unauthorized.html =404;
                        access_log      /var/log/nginx/error.log;
                }
        }
    }


You should show full config.

Sure, added. Thanks

https://nginx.org/r/location
location ^~ / { prevent matching to regexp locations. Just remove ^~.

If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.

